# Distributed cache issue in cloudera 5.0.1

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

Even though,the jars from the HDFS location is deleted, Hadoop caches it somehow and I am able to run my MR job. This seems weird as the MR job should have failed since it shouldn't have found the jars in the classpath. It is also seen stale jars being kept in the Distributed cache, even if the jars are updated. Please help.

Comment: Try to restart yarn server. Hope it helps.